# Why can't Simple Search find any results?

Tags: simple-search

I have used Simple Search many times on many sites, but for some reason on this one, I am not getting any results when I know the keywords are there.

```
http://192.196.159.46/membership/business-search
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
{exp:search:simple_form channel="member_profiles" search_in="entries" result_page="/membership/business-keyword-results" where="any"}
<label for="keywords">Search:</label><br />
<input type="text" name="keywords" id="keywords" value="" size="30" maxlength="100" placeholder="keywords">
<input type="submit" value="Search" class="submit">
{/exp:search:simple_form}
```

Is there something simple I am overlooking? I would even settle for something complex.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you certain the fields in which you know the keywords exist are set to be searchable? Note also that `search_in="entries"` will not search entry titles.

Comment: Hi Derek. You are a very handy second pair of eyes to have around. Alas, the field was not set to be searchable, but is now and works correctly. Thank you.

Comment: Hey, @DerekHogue! Move your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you certain the fields in which you know the keywords exist are set to be searchable? That is likely the culprit.

Note also that `search_in="entries"` will not search entry titles.